# variables with special characters in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, we can set and read the session variables using SET and SELECTs:

```
SET FOO_BAR='foobar'
SELECT $FOO_BAR
```

But the variable I am dealing with has special character "." and the above statements don't work. I can get the SET to work by double quoting the variable name
`SET "FOO.BAR" = 'foobar'`

But `SELECT $"FOO.BAR"` does not work (or other variations of it)

I can use `SHOW VARIABLES like 'FOO.BAR'` and that works, but I was interested in getting select working so I can use it queries. Any idea how can I use select to read such variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GETVARIABLE() function to access these kinds of variables:

```
SET "FOO.BAR" ='foo.bar';
SELECT GETVARIABLE('FOO.BAR');
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html#session-variable-functions